# Plot Natural Log and Derivative Help

Tags: plotting

```
h[x_] := Log[2 x + xSin[x]]

h'[x_] := (2 + Sin[x] + xCos[x])/(2 x + xSin[x])

Plot[{h[x], h'[x]}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

Whenever I try to plot these two functions the plot turns up blank with two axes.

Please halp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the correct syntax and let Mathematica do the derivative:

```
h[x_] := Log[2 x + x Sin[x]]

Plot[{h[x], h'[x]}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been spending hours on this simple problem.

Comment: @user12967 You need a space to mean "multiplication" and an apostrophe to mean "derivative". As in Math ;)